# Black screen on admin login in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, black-screen-of-death

I have four accounts on my computer, two for guests, one is for a family member and one is admin's.

On login to the admin account, the windows screen goes black with a working cursor, while on the other accounts, the windows screen is working fine.

Then I disabled some non-Microsoft programs that were in the list of the `Startup` tab of the `Task Manager`, then restart the pc, then the admin account started to work fine. After shutdown the PC and start it again with admin login on the next day, it keeps displaying black dead screen on admin's account.

Then I google it and follow this path `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` of `Registry Editor` and `modify` the `Shell` where its value was `explorer.exe` then on restarting the PC admin account had started to working fine.

But after another shut down and turn on the pc, the admin account keeps displaying a black dead screen.

I want to know what causes this black screen of death and how to permanently fix it so that the admin's login started to work normally.

System Details -

```
    OS: Windows 10 Version 1803
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G4560 @ 3.50GHz
```

Comment: You wouldn't have checked the "no gui boot" box in msconfig, by chance? The black screen should be temporary if you disabled the "Users must enter password" in netplwiz, but if you have enabled it, then basically your login screen is there, just not visible.

Comment: @Didier, "no gui boot" box is not check. And login screen is looking normally after inputting password and on clicking `enter` it is displaying black screen.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I thought the black screen showed up BEFORE logon screen. So, three things you can do: 1) When you're in front of the black screen, press the following keys simultaneously: Windows-Ctrl-Shift-B (this will restart your display driver) ; 2) and 3) involve booting in Safe Mode, by Shift-right-click on the Power button at the bottom right corner of the logon screen and choose Restart. When your PC has booted, in Startup settings, press the F4 key. Once in Safe Mode, open regedit and go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows NT \ CurrentVersion \ Winlogon. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 In the right-hand pane, look for the line that says "Shell". If the value for that string isn't "explorer.exe" (could be blank, or contain another value), double-click on "Shell", and in the value line, enter "explorer.exe" (no quotes). Click OK. Close Regedit, and restart your PC normally. If the black screen is still there upon reboot, go back into Safe Mode, open Device Manager (Windows-X, then Device Manager), right-click on the line of your display adapter / graphics card, and uninstall the device (if you're offered to delete the driver too, check that box). Restart normally. Tell us.

Comment: BTW, when you're in front of the black screen, have you tried Ctrl-Alt-Del? What happens when you do?

Comment: @Didier, on Ctrl-Alt-Del it displays task manager, lock... all that.

Comment: OK, that's good. What if you open Task Manager, go to File > New task, enter "explorer.exe" (no quotes) and press Enter?

Comment: I did that but after shutdown and turn on the pc it went back to black screen on admin login

Comment: then I go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\System Settings` and uncheck the `Turn on fast startup`, after that on turning on the pc admin login started to work normally. Is unchecking the  `Turn on fast startup` good?

Comment: Yes, in your case it's good because it solved your problem! :-D Fast Startup is something between full-blown cold boot and hibernation, in the sense that Windows writes system data and drivers to disk when you shutdown your PC, and it makes the next boot supposedly faster (not sure about that), but if the data Windows saves are corrupted somehow, it can lead to the kind of predicament you were facing. Leave it that way if you think your PC is booting fast enough, but after a couple reboots, you can try and enable it back again. The corrupted data will have been cleared by then.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.